# Assertion Failure on getting a key from NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I'd like to understand how could the function below sometimes generates a Swift "_assertionFailure" in line:
if let s = dict![key] as? String

I suppose that if dict![key] is not found, a nil would return, so the if let would get a nil value and the condition would fail, with no errors, no assertions. Where I am getting wrong?

```
func getDictKey(_ dict: NSDictionary?, key: String) -> String?
{
    var value: String?;

    if (dict != nil && !key.isEmpty)
    {
        if let s = dict![key] as? String {
            value = s;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is very, very objective-c-ish.

In Swift you can simply write

```
func getDictKey(_ dict: NSDictionary?, key: String) -> String?
{
    return dict?[key] as? String
}
```

It contains all checks except the empty string check. The question mark after `dict`*aborts* the chain if the dictionary is `nil`.

---

You should not use `NSDictionary` in Swift but a more meaningful naming

```
func getValue(from dict: [String:Any]?, forKey key: String) -> String?
{
    return dict?[key] as? String
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and give you a feedback. Thx!